# Find the subspace that contribute in a relevant way to the correlation of two vectors?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

Let take two discrete temporal series $x_i$ and $y_i$ where $i$ indicate the time and suppose that they are in general random and not correlated, except in a specific interval of time, e.g. some minutes around midnight every days.

I would like to find the subspace (time interval) in which the two series are correlated and compute a Pvalue that measure the "relevance" of the correlation in the subspace, taking into account that this correlation can arise just by chance because of the freedom in selecting the subspace.

I used as example time series to try to better explain the problem, but actually I'm interested in correlating vectors in general, for example vectors of gene expression in many biological samples, so I cannot use something like periodicity to extract the relevant subspace in which the series of numbers correlate.

In the following I try to formalize a bit the problem.

Given two vectors $x$ and $y$ of size $N$, i.e. two series of $N$ real numbers, $x_i$ indicate a real number (scalar), as well as $y_i$.
$N$ is the dimension of the space in which $x$ and $y$ live.

Suppose that the Pearson correlation $P(x,y)=0.2$, meaning that they are poorly correlated if we consider the entire space made of $N$ dimension.

Lets consider a subspace made of $M$ dimension whit $M<N$, $x'$ is the ordered series of real number taken from $x$, whit the same order of $x$, but $x_i \in x' \Leftrightarrow i $ is a dimension of the big original space that is also included in the smaller subspace in which $x'$ and $y'$ live.

It is possible that $P(x',y')>>P(x,y)$

Finding the subspace in which the two vectors are more correlated is not difficult (if the vectors have mean 0 and variance 1 then $P(x,y)=\sum ^n _{i=1}x_iy_i$ and each dimension $i$ contribute to the Pearson whit $x_iy_i$) but I need to asses how many dimension are actually relevant.

Comment: Maybe check out bumphunting? That's a tool to detect when a patch of genes (called an "island") are more expressed than the surrounding area. You might be able to create a vector of adaptive pearson correlations over the geneome, and detect "bumps" in the absolute value of the correlations. What do you think?

Comment: Thank @gabriel, it sound interesting. Have you some publication to suggest on the topic?